# I earn +3 reputation without vote, answer, comment, 8 min after post?

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-history

I earn +3 reputation without explaination, vote, comment, or answer for my new topic: [rake assets:precompile bug with rails and compass and "*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809308/rake-assetsprecompile-bug-with-rails-and-compass-and)

how know the reason ?

Comment: You have one upvote (+5) and one downvote (-2).

Comment: @PeterJ How can you see that?

Comment: @Matrix when you get to 1000 rep, you can see the vote splits on a question.

Comment: He has the "View vote counts" privilege, which is at 1K reputation. At that point, you just click on the number to see the split

Comment: why this acces is not always granted for owned topic? :s

Comment: @Matrix If you go to your own reputation history, it should show you a breakdown of your reputation change on a post.

Comment: @Emrakul no, there is only +3, and nothing more...

Comment: @Matrix I mean [your reputation history page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2505904/matrix?tab=reputation), in which you can [click the dropdown button](http://prntscr.com/5pem23) to expand your rep history on a particular post

Comment: ok I see. Not realy practice.

Comment: @Matrix You could also install [this extension](http://stackapps.com/q/3082/29148) which gives you the ability to view the vote counts on all SE sites without needing 1000 reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should answer your question:

[image: 1000 rep picture]

Once you hit 1000 reputation, you unlock the [ability to view vote counts as an established user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user). That's what your post looks like for me after I click on the 0.

Everything makes sense. One upvote on the question (+5 reputation) and one downvote on the question (-2 reputation) adds up to a net gain of 3 reputation.

If you had wanted to see this for yourself, you could click on your profile, and then click on "view more" in your reputation box, which takes you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2505904/matrix?tab=reputation), and then click on the small green bar all the way on the right, which shows the change for today:

[image: N/A]